# Converting VB6 Optional Parameter to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6

I have a VB6 function that has an optional date interval parameter that I'm trying to convert to C#. I'm also not sure of the best way to handle this in code. Here is the VB function declaration:

```
Private Function ReplaceDateTextNonBinary(psTable as String, psColumn as String, psColumnOffSet as String, psDateFormat as String, Optional psInterval as String = "n")
```

This function uses the optional parameter in the following DateAdd method call.

```
DateTime = DateAdd(psInterval, oSQL.Value(psColumnOffset), Date$)
```

Here is how I was planning to convert the function declaration to C# using the params keyword.

```
private static bool ReplaceDateTextNonBinary(string psTable, string psColumn, string pColumnOffset, string psDateFormat, params string psInterval)
```

I think this would work but I'm don't know how to code this that would take any date interval as a string. I was thinking of using a switch...case statement but that didn't seem very elegant.

Any thoughts.

Comment: The C# `params` keyword is similar to the `ParamArray` VB keyword, so it's not what you're looking for here.

Comment: Please use Google before you ask for help.  The obvious query is "c# optional parameter".  Take the first hit.

Comment: Sorry for posting a duplicate question. I've been looking on Google and on here most of the day and came up with nothing. I'm not sure how to phase the question any better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an optional parameter in C# just like this:

```
private static bool ReplaceDateTextNonBinary(string psTable, 
                                             string psColumn, 
                                             string pColumnOffset, 
                                             string psDateFormat, 
                                             string psInterval = "n")
```

If the optional parameter isn't passed, it'll get the value `"n"`. Note that optional parameters must be listed last in the method signature. Also note this is a C# 4.0 feature and won't work with earlier versions of C# (in which case, simple overloading is probably your best bet).

See: [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

The prior to 4.0 way to do it would be something like this:

```
private static bool ReplaceDateTextNonBinary(string psTable, 
                                             string psColumn, 
                                             string pColumnOffset, 
                                             string psDateFormat)
{
    return ReplaceDateTextNonBinary(psTable,
                                    psColumn,
                                    pColumnOffset,
                                    psDateFormat,
                                    "n");
}

private static bool ReplaceDateTextNonBinary(string psTable, 
                                             string psColumn, 
                                             string pColumnOffset, 
                                             string psDateFormat, 
                                             string psInterval)
{
    // your implementation here
}
```